# 18.04 after update, keeps reconnecting Ethernet and then drops connection?

Tags: ethernet

After recent update, Ubuntu keeps connecting and then dropping Ethernet connection. Any idea? I have tried to switch cables & plugs to make sure it's not a hardware issue. I have also done "sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms" to reinstall driver. A few partial solutions I found online suggest checking "/etc/network/interfaces," and this is what I've got:

```
 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
```

That's all, looks pretty wrong compared to those solutions, but I have no knowledge at all to know how should I fix it. I am on DELL XPS 13 9380. Thanks for the help!!

Update:

Following @tai271828's reply, here's output from lspci -nn (and yes, I am using a dongle. Thanks!):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e34] (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3ea0]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9df9] (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9ded] (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9def] (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9de8] (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9de9] (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9de0] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dbc] (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dbe] (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9db0] (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9db4] (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d84] (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dc8] (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9da3] (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9da4] (rev 30)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
04:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
04:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
04:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
05:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d2] (rev 02)
39:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d4] (rev 02)
6e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix Device [1c5c:1527]
```

Update:

I switched to other Ethernet-to-USB-c dongles and they all worked fine. The only one that doesn't work after this update is Dell DA300, which is only 4 months old and hasn't been anywhere but on my desk. I've also tried to plug Ethernet cable to USB-c adapter and then plugged that adapter to DA300, and it worked. It's hard to believe this is just due to broken hardware, since it can always detect connection when plugging in an Ethernet cable but fails to establish connection, but I have no way to rule out the possibility.

Update:

From journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager, showing immediate connection/disconnection for the reason I don't understand

```
<info>  [1564007509.2735] device (enxc8f7509d89c6): carrier: link connected
<info>  [1564007509.2740] device (enxc8f7509d89c6): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1564007510.2992] device (enxc8f7509d89c6): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Comment: For me, your `/etc/network/interfaces` looks good. Could you provide the output of `lspci -nn` for debugging?

Comment: btw, if I understand correctly, Dell XPS 13 9380 does not have ethernet ports. Did you use a dongle or something?

Comment: Because it was after an update what does `uname -r` report for the kernel version?

Comment: 4.18.0-25-generic

Comment: The this is sounds like a kernel or network-manager issue. You may report the bug with `ubuntu-bug linux` and `ubuntu-bug network-manager` on Launchpad.